# Dynamically applying an array of parameters to a block

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I need a way of dynamically applying an array of parameters to a block.  The block could have any number of parameters, of any type.

I know that the number and type of parameters in the array will agree.

I have already looked at casting the block to [`CTBlockLiteral`](https://github.com/ebf/CTObjectiveCRuntimeAdditions).  This provides access to an `invoke` method.

A block with the signature `(void(^)(NSString* arg0,NSString* arg1))` can be called like this:  `blockRef->invoke(nil, @"foo", @"bar");`.

How can this be generalised to any number of parameters, where the arity and type is not known at compile time?

EDIT:  To be clear, no I don't want to change my blocks to accept varargs, arrays or whatever.  These blocks can have whatever signatures they want, and I have the parameters in an array.  How can I pass these parameters to the block?  It feels like I want something similar to Javascript's `apply` function.

Comment: Using varargs? https://gist.github.com/JacobOscarson/2783763

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis no, the block needs to be blissfully unaware that this has happened.

Comment: Sounds like you're asking "how do I reproduce Javascript `apply` function with blocks in Objective-C?" Blocks aren't suited for this. Possibly `NSInvocation`, depending upon what you're trying to do. Can you describe the broader business problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: "How can this be generalised to any number of parameters, where the arity and type is not known at compile time?" How can you write the call if the rarity and type are not known at compile time?

Comment: I'm writing a framework which marshals iOS method calls through javascript in a webview.  I want these blocks to act as callbacks, and for my framework to be able to invoke them, passing parameters provided from js.  Seems this would be very easy if I restrict it to blocks of known signature (e.g. a single NSString parameter), but not for arbitrary params.

Comment: This library might help (but I haven't tried it): https://github.com/robrix/Obstruct

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to do it

1) Using the ellipsis, also called variable arguments in C
2) Passing a dictionary / collection as parameter
3) Passing an object that encapsulates the data.

```
(void(^)(id allMyArgs)) {
   NSArray *args = (NSArray *)allMyArgs;
   ...
}
```

can be called like this:

```
NSArray *aux = @[ arg1, arg2, ... argN ];
blockRef->invoke(nil, aux);
```

Without changing the signature, using a pointer argument to pass a pointer to an array:

```
NSArray *aux = @[ arg1, arg2, ... argN ];
NSString *par = (NSString *)aux; 

blockRef->invoke(nil, par, @"bar");
```

Defining the block and accessing the parameters

```
(void(^)(NSString* arg0,NSString* arg1)) {

   NSArray *pars = (NSArray*)args0;

   ...
}
```

Comment: Right, this isn't what I need.  My block could look like this `(void(^)(NSString *arg0, int arg1)) {}`, or it could look like this `(void(^)(BOOL arg0, NSString *arg1, int arg2, NSString *arg3)) {}`, I don't care.  All I want to do is apply the arguments to it.

Comment: In that case use the ellipsis, as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1405/_index.html

Comment: I really don't think this is what I need.  Can you show an example of how I can use ellipsis to invoke a block with the signature `(void(^)(NSString *arg0, int arg1)) {}`, without changing the block's signature?

Comment: To use an ellipsis you need to change the signature, so that the block can recieve an ellipsis. The only way i can see to use multiple parameters without changing the block signature, is to use arg0 (as it is a pointer) and pass a pointer to a different object (like a diccionary or an array) and, in the block, type cast to the real object from NSString

Comment: Right, I don't want to do that... so this isn't what I need!